# Typescript nested generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

How do I nest the same type that uses generics?

```
interface programConfig<T extends Record<string, any>> {
  // other types removed; not relevant to the question
  commands?: { [key: string]: programConfig<???> }; // how do I type this?
}
```

More complete [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGBOD2BzWBDAtgYXgOwGYEtEAeAFSggA9gJsATAZygCUIBjeWWo+4WfbRABooKbCAB8UALzM2HLjz4DhoiZJkBvAFBQo8MMHw56AfgBcUbbt0BtANJR+UANYQQ8XFBIBdC1eu6AG4oADb4tCjAHOZQABQAlNKSJPbeOtYAvukZgukAFqK0IRCwMbERwCgWJIlSkoHw4bm67GhohaZ+UDauIBaK-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) example that shows what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: What do you want that type to be? Pass in `T` if you want it to be the exact same.

Comment: @Chase - I want it to be its own record.  The record is currently inferred based on the calling code.  If I pass in `T` then all nested instances use the same record as the root instance, which isn't what I want.  The example should be more clear

Comment: I have the feeling it's not possible. You would need `commands` to be generic, but in TypeScript, only type aliases, interfaces, classes, constructors, functions, and methods can be generic, but properties, objects, and values can't. You would essentially need `commands?<U>: { [key: string]: programConfig<U> };` See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a second generic to encompass the sub elements of the programConfig, in this example I constrained the inner ones to not allow a 3rd level of nesting since supporting arbitrary nesting would be annoying and hopefully not necessary

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQCEEGcoAUYD2A5jAgLYDCBYcIRAPACqpQAe0YAJlqgEpRICMTvSwQY4IgBpUAVzABrMAQDuYAHyp1Ab2CpUBAA4QQ1LAH4AXKl379AbQDSqcKgVQAngTipGAXWtbO30ANwQAGxBOBAghK1QACgBKVABeTUYnPz07AF8c3KkcgAsELnDYeIToiARrRhT01BCCKOB88Gh4ZDRDQhJyKho6AHUQCGKqMjIy7iYWdiguHn5BYVFxSRl5JVUNGQBlWQAjBY5uPgEhETEJMGlLtZvN++3FZTV1L7Oli8wcfDEUiUai0BiMTRBQTTWYWQJOFxgNyebyoI7HAIYbB4frAoZg+jorLqfL5YBIcLYHiAgZkeZsc4rK7rW5bOTvPbqGRTMg8Bm-JlPDZ3B6ra7Ctk7D4ab5QsziWRIWIwBKCYZEax9IGDUGjcaTAgw5ZMKQ8rDqFLaVCk4Dk+WoOAEAhpVBgKAqVA04EJIJGExmQI5fQAcjgMFk42DgWaESiMSE1mSaU0wewnDgwetRWCqbAIBm4SjNhjkRqCdQADlZGRjrAswVs6hSuVYImrWGIxAZGV8xEZBNJNbGpDUAB6UcO8PjVCzGd5gszmC9QiGWDhDyoCAeVecVDHbG76gGYymMA8BDHAghKBB1BqrAECoAOnCxASHfG3fnESSDZy0JmZZA2CR0CGA4Jj39M9wIg1Bg3EKAoCLK0wlLeMYETYc4LTDN61gkNVxgB8wGQwpb30MjYObTgKgwxIrQQqAZEI4j+2KQdciwq1x03Jc0BAHgtx3GceFZV5UBYo8BM3bcoF3bB2V2NRyLse9HygF830Y5jYGI39YMovICnaJIAG5gCAA)

```
interface BaseProgramConfig<T extends Record<string, unknown> >{
  options?: {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      validator?: () => T[K]
    }
  },
  handler?: (data: T) => void
}
interface programConfigWithCommands<T extends Record<string, unknown>, Sub extends Record<string, Record<string, unknown>>> extends BaseProgramConfig<T> {
  commands?: {[K in keyof Sub]: BaseProgramConfig<Sub[K]>}
}

class Program<T extends Record<string, unknown>, Comms extends Record<string, Record<string, unknown>>> {
  constructor(config: programConfigWithCommands<T,Comms>) { }
}

const foo = new Program({
  options: {
    'fruit': { validator: () => 'asdf' },
    'animal': { validator: Number },
  },
  handler: ({ fruit, animal, thing }) => { // fruit and animal are properly typed based on options above
    console.log(fruit, animal)
  },
  commands: {
    foo: {
      options: {
        'tree': { validator: () => 'asdf' },
        'person': {},
      },
      handler: ({ tree, person, thing }) => { // tree is typed as string, person is typed as unknown
        console.log(tree, person)
      },
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I was playing with something like this but couldn't get it to work.  This doesn't either, as the args in the last `handler` are still typed as `any`.  Also it unfortunately does need arbitrary levels of nesting (or at least one more practically speaking).  This is legacy code that I was trying to not change (just add types to), but I'm leaning towards ditching the nested config in favor of `{commands: new Program({...})}` which would be a fairly minimal codemod.

Comment: @Nobody I updated it so it works properly with one level of nesting, I'm not sure how you could do it with 3 levels just because I'm not sure where those sub-elements would even be stored.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen thank you for editing. I have tried `F-bounded quantification` but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `new Program` again, like here:

```js
type programConfig<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> = {
  options?: {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      validator?: () => T[K]
    }
  },
  handler?: (data: T) => void,
  commands?: { [key: string]: Program<Record<string,unknown>> }; // here use sub-programs that have nothing to do with T
}

class Program<T extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> {
  constructor(config: programConfig<T>) { }
}

const foo = new Program({
  options: {
    'fruit': { validator: () => 'asdf' },
    'animal': { validator: Number },
  },
  handler: ({ fruit, animal, thing }) => { // fruit and animal are properly typed based on options above
    console.log(fruit, animal)
  },
  commands: {
    foo: new Program({
      options: {
        'tree': { validator: () => 'asdf' },
        'person': {},
      },
      handler: ({ tree, person, thing }) => { // tree and person are typed in the same way and Program of any type is accepted in commands
        console.log(tree, person)
      },
    })
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGBOD2BzWBDAtgYXgOwGYEtEAeAFSggA9gJsATAZygCUIBjeWWo+4WfbRABooKbCAB8UALzM2HLjz4DhoiZJkBvAFBQo8MMHw56AfgBcUbbt0BtANJR+UANYQQ8XFBIBdC1eu6AG4oADb4tCjAHOZQABQAlNKSJPbeOtYAvukZgukAFqK0IRCwMbERwCgWJIlSkoHw4bm67GhohaZ+UDauIBaK-Ii+UAAKCMjoRCzsnNy8g4IArtjO2PAA7tjikhkA3FAA9AdQeSXQi-TQ9IsARgC0cEioaIzABcAnKIHQa2+DUFEoLR4FB1vg3l4tFktKwQih6Iwxk9JmRKNQ6IxpvI5kohCIxOpZDMFPNlPi1JZ0uxsIpFqworBYtSCIgLI8JpgcCzSOJEhooFlodSeFBcPAQTJsBB1qNxs9Yv59IZjH50roAOS4WCLcHqrrBMIVDgWBJJKDq+G0XDqgXNawW7D4dohPWWKAG8KRY1QAByizQNxKtuydoKdGKsBN-K1OuAKkdzuEfwEAtqkn5R1F2vB+No+KdoREsGgj0gsBCIAB4AgeZu8JremwegMRhpIhu8G+aqgwvgxQAdCEkLEY+D4wWQvEQ1T4G0OqqAmL4BYpTKkRyFd3dErW-QFwF7bwIBBXfyPUbI3E0+bLdbgwf7WX6DhTzkt-eD2GiiUowDixBhCfHAkzyf4MmvDNjiPaBChgEpnybFBiyrSA8ycN4rnQaB1hQStYPXZ49E8VQUOgfBGBQVhWAgAwGycVp2gxd8WmMPsIEHYdoMA+CcCnB83wCcDsiheJdiAA)

Comment: Yeah, this is my fallback plan :)  But it's legacy code that's used all over our codebase so I'm trying to avoid it